# What is the instagram style of arranging photos called?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the name of this arranging style? Is there some source to read about it?

Can someone briefly explain how the frame can adjust automatically with different photo sizes using html5 or javascript?

Comment: You mean how they're cropped/proportionally sized? You can use a div and set the background to the image, then specify `background-size: cover;`...

Comment: A screenshot might really help here.  Point out the thing(s) you have a question about.